# Trying to sync geth node (state snapshot generation)

Tags: go-ethereum

Is this behavior normal? Seems to be taking forever and the accounts/slots number is not even changing.

[image: nothin]

Comment: if your hardware or you network speed is slow, that would be the issue

Comment: I dont think this is the issue... I have a downlaod speed of 100 mbps, and hardware is a macbook pro with an SSD + 8 GB ram